# sequelize migration cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sequelize.js

I am getting an error that says cannot read properties of undefined while attempting a migration to create a junction table. The migration file for the table in question looks like this.

```
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable("MovieGenres", {
      MovieId: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "Movies",
        },
        key: "id",
        allowNull: false,
      },
      GenreId: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "Genres",
        },
        key: "id",
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  },
```

The actual model table is created using sequelize-typescript and it looks like this.

```
@Table({ timestamps: false })
class MovieGenres extends Model {
  @ForeignKey(() => Movies)
  MovieId: number;
  @ForeignKey(() => Genres)
  GenreId: number;
}
export default MovieGenres;
```

I tried searching on google and no one has the same problem as I do. Also I think the issue is that somehow I am not creating the object properties correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get types of fields directly from `Sequelize` parameter:

```js
type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
```